# Expected bool, found i32 when using the operator %

Tags: rust

Maybe this is normal behavior, but someone can help me with this:

```
trait Flujo<T: std::clone::Clone> {
    fn filter<F: Fn(T)->bool>(&self, prot: F);
}   

impl<T: std::clone::Clone> Flujo<T> for Test<T> {
     fn filter<F: Fn(T)->bool>(&self, prot: F ){ 
     ..//
     }
}
```

in this simple test works

```
test.filter(|x| -> bool{ 

    true
});
```

but when I try this

```
test.filter(|x| -> bool{ 
    //return x % 2 ? true : false;

    if x % 2 {   <-- Error
      return true;            
    } else{
      return false;
    }
});
```

---

Error:

```
mismatched types:
 expected `bool`,
    found `i32` [E0308]
if value % 2 {
   ^~~~~~~~~
```

---

I searched and read, but the second link not quite understand, can someone explain me why this fails.

https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#arithmetic-operators

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Rem.html

---

Update:

You can see with this test, it is not the same code, but the same error is obtained:

<kbd>[play.rust](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=c4d931838894b202e52c111c31d0b9f1&version=stable&backtrace=0)</kbd>

Comment: @VeronikaPrüssels you have absolutely right, it is a stupid question sorry for it but did not see him  I would have to be tested more, the first thing I did was search the documentation and and I do not analyze well perhaps influenced by other things http://ideone.com/LHtu8p

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The type of `x % 2` matters. It is an integer, but `if` expects a boolean value. In this respect, Rust is a bit more like Java, and less as C.

This works, probably as expected:

```
fn b(value: i32) {
    if (value % 2) == 0 {
        println!("1");        
    } else{
        println!("2");
    }
}

fn main() {
    b(2);
}
```

Exactly as @Veronika Prüssels has commented at the same time.

Comment: I was more aware of the new language, which did not see this error sorry for it, and thanks for your time

Answer (score 8):

In C, C++ and probably other languages, integers can be implicitly converted to booleans. That's not the case in Rust: Rust will never perform implicit conversions between primitive types (whether it's integer to integer, integer to float, integer to boolean, etc.), in order to avoid surprises.

All you need to do is add `!= 0` to the expression that evaluates to an integer (you may need to add parentheses to get the correct operator precedence) to turn it into a boolean expression that behaves like in C or C++.

```
test.filter(|x| -> bool { 
    if x % 2 != 0 {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
});
```

or just:

```
test.filter(|x| x % 2 != 0);
```

Comment: you are right https://ideone.com/LHtu8p but I would have to be tested more, the first thing I did was search the documentation and not I stop thinking about what you said thanks for the declaration of implicit conversions, I was more aware of the error messaging, I will not try == 0 or otherwise